# Do the builtin types (c, d, i, f, etc.) have CONVERSION_EXI_* functions? And if so, how to find them?

Tags: abap

The `WRITE` statement has a lot of options, so I was wondering, does it call CONVERSION_EXIT_* functions, or how does it print the primitive data types in so many ways?

And if it does use CONVERSION_EXIT_*s, what are those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primitive data types (`DATA foo TYPE n LENGTH 10`) do not have any conversion exits (`ALPHA`, etc.) assigned to them.

- You can choose them manually, for example with

  WRITE ... TO ... USING EDIT MASK '==ALPHA'.
- or they can be assigned to a data dictionary domain (transaction code `SE11`). In this case, they are implicitly called for example:

  - by the screen (dynpro) processing (unless turned off explicitly).
  - by WRITE

    DATA(langu) = CONV syst-langu( 'E' ). " domain SYLANGU has conv.exit ISOLA

    DATA text TYPE c LENGTH 2.

    WRITE langu TO text. " conv.exit ISOLA converts 'E' into 'EN'

Except `WRITE`, ABAP itself does very little to support conversion exits - which is a good thing because the conversion should take place only at the input/output borders of the program and not internally.

It's a good idea to keep all of the data in the internal format as long as you're working on it and only convert it right before the output takes place.